# stop python subprocess after n bytes or lines in proc.stdout.read()

Tags: python, subprocess

I'd like to run a subprocess in python until the subprocess has outputted a certain number of bytes or lines. After this point, I'd like to terminate it. Is this possible with subprocess?

Here's what I have so far:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
#kill after reaching n bytes of output, proc.terminate()
out, errors = proc.communicate()
```

Thanks!

Comment: lines is easier, certain byte you may try pexcept

Answer (score 0):

One fairly straightforward way to do this would be to redirect the output to a program that will do the byte/line counting for you, for example:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
head = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-n', '20'], stdin=proc.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdout.close()
out, errors = head.communicate()
```

I'm not sure how portable this method is, I was only able to test on Linux however on Windows you should be able to use the `more` command for similar behavior.

Closing `proc.stdout` is necessary so that `proc` receives SIGPIPE when `head` exits.